# Can't Authenticate Maven to Access Azure Artifacts from ADO Pipeline

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops

I have a azure pipeline that runs in the cloud and in there, I basically want to run a Blackduck scan. To make it easy, the blackduck task runs a maven command to build the dependency tree. In order to do so, it scans all the dependencies in my pom.xml.

I currently have 2 feeds in Azure DevOps. 1 feed that store external libraries and 1 to store internal libraries developed in house. All the dependencies that are external, the maven command is able to retrieve but not the internal one. I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized error.

I have updated my pom.xml to include the credentials to connect to azure artifact as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/maven?view=azure-devops). I have also updated the settings.xml file to include the connection as well. Before the maven command is run, I have added the Maven authenticate task

Yml pipeline:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "Modify Settings.xml"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $xmlPom = [xml]"<server>
                <id>Pack-All</id>
                <username>Bob</username>
                <password>$(ado.pat)</password>
              </server>"
              
          $file = "settings.xml"
          $origin = "$(M2_HOME)\conf"

          $xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument

          $fileXml = resolve-path(“$origin\$file”)

          $xdoc.load($fileXml)

          $xdoc.settings.servers.AppendChild($xdoc.ImportNode($xmlPom.server, $true))

          $xdoc = [xml] $xdoc.OuterXml.Replace(" xmlns=`"`"", "")

          $xdoc.Save(“$origin\$file”)
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
      displayName: 'Maven Authenticate'
      inputs:
        artifactsFeeds: 'Pack-All'
- task: SynopsysDetectTask@2  
      displayName: "Run Black Duck analysis"
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.blackduck }}', 'true'))
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        Products: 'BD'
        BlackDuckService: 'Black Duck'
        DetectVersion: 'latest'
        DetectArguments: '--detect.project.name=$(Build.Repository.Name)Test --detect.binary.scan.file.path=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\app.war --detect.maven.build.command=-DmavenFeedAuthenticate=true'
```

Maven command that the Blackduck task executes:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.cmd -DmavenFeedAuthenticate=true dependency:tree -T1
```

Error Log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dimload-ms-app-agg: Could not resolve dependencies for project ca.test-ms-app-agg:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at ca.cn.boot:helpers:jar:0.4.28950: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ca.test.boot:helpers:jar:0.4.28950: Could not transfer artifact ca.test.boot:helpers:pom:0.4.28950 from/to Test-All (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Test-Int/_packaging/Pack-All/maven/v1): Authentication failed for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Test-Int/_packaging/Pack-All/maven/v1/ca/test/boot/helpers/0.4.28950/helpers-0.4.28950.pom 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 3):

From your Yaml Sample, you have added the `MavenAuthenticate` task.  This task will automatically generate a settings.xml for the target feed.

This file exists in the path `xxx\.m2\settings.xml`
[image]

So you don't need to add this file(`settings.xml`)manually. This can also help you simplify your code.

> Authentication failed for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.... 401 Unauthorized

The possible cause of this issue is that the build service account does not have sufficient permissions for the feed.

You could try the following steps:

1. Navigate to `Artifacts ->Target Feed ->Feed Settings -> Permission`.
2. Set the Project Build Service(`ProjectName Build Service(OrganizationName)`) As Contributor role within the target feed.

[image]

Or you could enable the option `Allow Project-Scoped Builds`.

[image]

On the other hand, from the feed URL, it seems to be an Organization-Scope feed.

You could check the `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` option is `Enabled` in `Project Settings -> Pipelines`.

You could try to disable the option.

Note: To disable this option, you need to disable the option in `Organization Settings-> Settings` first. Then you could disable the option in Project level.

Comment: I have removed he "Authenticate Maven" task. I verify the other options and I still get the 401 error. I just can't seem to authenticate Maven to access the artifacts

Comment: Thanks for your information. In this case, it may be that the authentication information is not passed to the command line. You could try to add the `-s settings.xml` in the command. For example: `--detect.maven.build.command="C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.cmd -f pom.xml -s path/settings.xml -gs path/settings.xml"`

Comment: On the other hand, you need to ensure that you have given the PAT sufficient permissions.  If possible, you could try to use `full access` option

Comment: In my case I needed to remove original settings.xml file, because the maven authenticate didnt override old data, and old token was already expired.